# DDR4 Routing Consideration on pcb (no DIMM)

Tags: fpga, layout, high-speed, ddr4, signal-routing

I need to route DDR4x2(3200MHz) to my FPGA.
my stackup is 12 Layers, TH Via only, and thickness of 2mm PCB.
my question regard which layer to route the FPGA to DDR4, when the two component on the TOP(L1).
one way: when I route from L1->L10->L1 the stub will be from L10->L12(only 2 layers) 
but the disadvantage is the long way that signal travel.
the second way: when I route from L1->L3->L1 the signal distance are shorter but the stub is longer(from L3->L12 for each via)
How can I know what is the better way to do it? I can simulate but I want to start with something and to do it faster, so maybe someone know rule of thumb about my stub/distance questions.

Comment: Backdrilling vias is not an option?

Comment: @SimonRichter Nop